# How can I animate bump or displacement node?

Tags: animation, node-editor

Is it possible to animate the texture of the object? For example I would like to make bump vector's strength higher and texture to change a bit through animation, but I can find that you can animate only location of the vectors and you can not animate nodes properties itself. Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can animates all the settings you want in your nodes, you just need to put your cursor where you want the change to happen in the *Timeline*, then in the *Node Editor* put your mouse on the factor you want to change and press <kbd>i</kbd> to insert a keyframe. Now, move your cursor in the Timeline and again go back in the *Node Editor*, change the factor and press <kbd>i</kbd> to insert a new keyframe, etc.

[image]